# WPF app not working when MaterialDesignThemes is installed

Tags: c#, wpf

```
Cannot resolve dependency on assembly code 'Microsoft.Windows.Design.Extensibility, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' because it is pre-installed
```

This error occurs as I mentioned above, when I install MaterialDesignThemes.

When I remove it from my project, everything is just fine.

Comment: It seem that the message is clear. Checks your project references and delete that package "Microsoft.Windows.Design.Extensibility" then try to install again

Comment: Where is the package located?@Romylussone

Answer (score -2):

I don't know why but the problem is solved randomly. The program is started somehow. But I will be happy to know the actual solution in case I encounter the same issue again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).